# Django multiple DB how to write router

Tags: python, django, django-database

I've got two DB, I've written a **router.py** that correctly manage write and read, but if the *read db the **default*** is down I cannot access also the write db getting the

```
class TestRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'read_app':
            return 'default'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'write_app':
            return 'write_db'        
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'write_app':
            return 'write_db'
        return None
```

and in **settings.py**:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['prj.dbrouter.TestRouter', ]
```

this is the error:

> cnn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory,
>   async=async)
>   OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused   Is the server running on host "192.168.2.1" and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

is there a way to say to django to ignore failure in connection to *default* db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error shows that the database to which you want to connect is not accepting request or listening from host "192.168.2.1".

In `postgresql.conf` file, change `listen_addresses = '*'`

Lemme elaborate what exactly you should do,

1. Add the database information in your `settings.py` and also information about the `routers.py` :

`settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'master': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
    'slave': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
SLAVE_DATABASES = ['slave']

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.your.routers.MasterSlaveRouter']
```

2. Create the `routers.py` which will handle switching the read and write request among the database mentioned in settings :

`routers.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
import socket


def test_connection_to_db(database_name):
    try:
        db_definition = getattr(settings, 'DATABASES')[database_name]
        s = socket.create_connection(
            (db_definition['HOST'], db_definition['PORT']), 5)
        s.close()
        return True
    except:
        return False


class MasterSlaveRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen slave.
        """
        if test_connection_to_db('master'):
            return 'master'
        return 'slave'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to master.
        """
        if test_connection_to_db('master'):
            return 'master'
        return 'slave'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the master/slave pool.
        """
        db_list = ('master', 'slave')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
```

So now if your master is down and slave is up. Request will be transferred accordingly and vice-versa. Make sure any one database is up.

HTH! :)